# Iframe stopping object tag in IE

Tags: php, object, iframe

I haven't been able to find a answer to my question by searching, but hopefully im not the only one with this problem.

At the moment im working on a webpage used for surveilence. I've got a page displaying 4 camera images as an embed tag + some buttons on the side for controls.
However im exeperiencing some problems with this in IE.

One of the control buttons appends a iframe to the HTML containing a page wich starts a auto download.
As soon as the button is clicked in IE the iframe seems to stop my video object tags from playing.
The objects starts playing again as soon as i reload the page but having to do that is just plain anoying.

Have anyone experienced something simular? 
Any ideas of why the Iframe seems to stop the object tag?

Comment: Problem with the number of concurrent connections to the same server maybe? (AFAIR [older] IE had that limit set quite low, to four I think.)

Comment: I think not. After some googling it apears that both IE 8 (wich im running) and chrome allows 6 connections and still only IE is the problem.

Comment: Try developer tools ([f12]) to check what network activity is actually going on. / Have you tried if exchanging the iframe for a separate popup window changes IE’s behavior?

Comment: Problem solved! Replaceing the iframe with a window.open did the trick.  Why i dident try this to begin with must be a riddle ;)

Comment: Does that page you show in the iframe/popup actually show any HTML content in addition to triggering the download? If not, it should also be possible to just assign the download URL to `location.href` – if the resource requested triggers the download dialog, then the current page does not get replaced by the browser.

Comment: No everything on that page is serverside. It only containts a function to create a bat file + headers needed for instantly downloading it. Thanks for your help. Post an answer and i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have you tried if exchanging the iframe for a separate popup window changes IE’s behavior?

As we figured out in comments, that seems to do the trick and stop IE from stopping videos from playing.

> it should also be possible to just assign the download URL to location.href – if the resource requested triggers the download dialog, then the current page does not get replaced by the browser.

That might spare you the use of an iframe or popup overall.